# asp.net email polling

Tags: asp.net, email, polling

I have a requirement at the moment where I need to have an Asp.net application poll a mailbox every few minutes to check for new mail then process that mail as data entry for a database.

Is there a way to have an Asp.net application behave like a task scheduler where it frequently polls a mail server to check for email?

Comment: Check out http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options:

1. Use [one of the Timer classes](http://www.google.co.uk/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=what%20timer%20class%20to%20use#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=what%20.net%20timer%20class%20to%20use&pbx=1&oq=what%20.net%20timer%20class%20to%20use&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=15359l18487l0l18903l7l6l0l0l0l4l1290l2726l2-1.2.0.1.0.1l5l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=d8e9f575001837d4&biw=1680&bih=925) to fire off a method every x ticks.
2. Do the same but as a [windows service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service) - this lets your application run without any users logged in.
3. Use the built in [task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) to execute your application.
4. Use the cache, set to expire after x minutes. Use the onRemoveCallback parameter to call a callback to repopulate the cache item (and execute your method).

Comment: Thanks Oded, 

1. Will the timer class keep the application active? 
2. What did you mean by "the same as a windows service"?

Comment: @Jacques - 1. Timers will fire on their own threads, so yes. 2. Instead of an asp.net app, use a windows service.

Comment: @Jacques - See option 4, probably the best for an asp.net application.

Comment: I think you should create a windows service its alot more reliable.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the cache option. Does it basically mean that the asp.net engine is monitoring the cache and when it expires it fires a certain event in which case I could wire an eventhandler to it? 
Kim - I would agree that a web service is the most appropriate route, but this is potentially going to be hosted in a shared environment so that limits my options.

Comment: @Jacques - Not exactly an event - it a delegate type. You specify a method to be called when the cache item expires it needs to match the [CacheItemRemovedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemremovedcallback.aspx) delegate signature.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there a way to have an Asp.net application behave like a task scheduler where it frequently polls a mail server to check for email?*

Not really because if there are no visitors in a given periode the asp.net application will close down until a new visitor enters the site. 
So i will recommand that you do it in a windows service!

Comment: Check out the Cache option mentioned in Oded's answer.